# TypeScript tsc > redirection of messages

Tags: typescript, tsc

I’ve just installed TypeScript as a Node.js package, and to my surprise it seems to be working straight away.  But I cannot find a way of intercepting any messages it might generate.  Doing the following with a greeter.ts file that has an intentional error

```
tsc greeter.ts > err.log
```

confirms that no redirection is occurring.  Anyone know a way round this?  I want to do this so I can pick up errors in my editor.

By the way, I’ve noticed that tsc only accepts lowercase file names.  Doing tsc GREETER.TS gives Error reading file "GREETER.TS": File not found.

In response to Sohnee’s comment:  No, tsc is definitely issuing an error message, it’s just that I cannot redirect it.  My greeter.ts file, complete with intentional error is:

```
function greeter(person) {
  return "Hello, " + person;
}
var user = "Jane User";
undeclared
document.body.innerHTML = greeter(user);
```

From an OS shell I get the following.

```
C:\K_F90\F90WX\BOOKS\THENOD~1>tsc greeter.ts
C:/K_F90/F90WX/BOOKS/THENOD~1/greeter.ts(7,0): The name 'undeclared' does not exist in the current scope
```

But when I try to redirect I get:

```
C:\K_F90\F90WX\BOOKS\THENOD~1>tsc greeter.ts > err.log
C:/K_F90/F90WX/BOOKS/THENOD~1/greeter.ts(7,0): The name 'undeclared' does not exist in the current scope
C:\K_F90\F90WX\BOOKS\THENOD~1>type err.log
C:\K_F90\F90WX\BOOKS\THENOD~1>
```

Pretty conclusive I think; an error message is being issued but is not being redirected to err.log, which is empty.

Answer (score 6):

The `>` operator only redirects stdout.  Errors are written to stderr.  To also redirect stderr, append `2>&1` to the command.  Backgrounder info [is here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx).

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thanks Diullei and Hans for the info.

Keith

Answer (score 2):

Try use:

`tsc greeter.ts > err.log 2>&1`

this worked good to me.